# Update dynamically image source

Tags: css, angular, image

I have an Ionic Angular app and I'm trying to update img src dynamically.

```
  let element = <HTMLImageElement>document.getElementById(`myImage${index}`);
  console.log(this.articleCards[index].images[this.articleImageIndex])
  element.src = this.articleCards[index].images[this.articleImageIndex];
```

HTML

```
<img #tinderCardImage 
  id="myImage{{index}}" 
  [src]="article.images[0]" 
  [alt]="article.name" >
```

I can see in "Network" debugger that the new image src is downloaded, but impossible to update/refresh the image displayed...In "Element" debugger I get the initial image.

Moreover, I have a second component where everything works perfectly....

So, If someone has an idea please

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `src` dynamically on html itself

```
[src]="articleCards[index].images[articleImageIndex]"
```

Comment: I have forgotten to tell you that I have 5 cards, so when I use your code, I'm loading 5 new images...
For my performance is not great... soryy

Comment: Can you please show me more code? or provide a stackblitz? I can help you to optimized that too.